# Efficient way to store multiple data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I need to track user tasks. So i came up with few ideas, please suggest which is efficient and good. So the user has around 6 tasks to finish up when they login for first time, lets say `task1,task2.....task6`. ( tasks are subjective to change in near future )

**Approach 1:**
Create a table with 10 columns ( extra 4 columns for safety if we need to extend like more than 6 tasks)

```
Table UserTasks:
task1 task2 task3 task4 .......    task9 task10
```

**Approach 2**
Create a table with three columns and have new rows for each tasks

**Approach 3**
Create a table with array to store all task results (as am using postgres)

```
Table UserTasks:
id    task                         date
1     [task1:True, task2:false]
```

**Approach 4**
Just create a table with **VarChar** and add custom data to it. For example, planning to add task1 if task1 completed and concatenate task2 if task2 completed

```
Table UserTasks:
id       task                date
1        task1,task2,task3
```

These are the ideas which developed, please help to pick a good approach. The thing is, these data will be READ too often. There wont be any DELETE to this date. A single user would be probably read this data at least 10 times when they logged in so performance is my obvious concern

Comment: ?Use single integer as bit flag (0 no tasks, 1 task 1, 2 task 2, 3 tasks 1 and 2 together, 4 task 3 etc)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Aproach 2 is the most flexible one. Aproach 4 is an absolute no-go.

Comment: You need to more clearly define what you wan to  know about a task.Then perhaps you can answer your own question by answering a few question  about the tasks.  Is the task finished? How much time did it take? When did user  start working or plans to start on task (if any)? When was task completed or planned to complete (if any). Can there be multiple users on a single task? If so how much total time did/ will it take? What was the contribution of each user? Other questions? At a basic level the only option is **Approach 2**, but perhaps with considerable expansion.

Comment: Basically those tasks are just registration task ( consider that as a course of actions which needs to be done after someone register themselves ) . It doest need to keep track of time etc. All i need is to know if the task1 is completed or not @Belayer

Comment: If Approach 2 is flexible, wont that create huge space consumption ? As there would be minimum of 6 tasks and it may increase in future ! Thus, if there is a million of users then it will take 6 millions of rows ! But in approach 1 it just take 1 million rows @Belayer